# Reference for convex partitions

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

I am looking for a reference for the following result:

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a linear order and let $\Pi$ be a partition of $X$ into convex subsets.

Then the relation $x\preceq y$ defined by $\forall P,Q\in \Pi,(x\in P\wedge y\in Q \rightarrow (\exists (p,q)\in P\times Q,(p\leq q)))$ is a quasi order. Moreover, for $x,y \in X$ we have $\exists P \in \Pi,x,y \in P$ if and only if $x\preceq y\wedge y \preceq x$ holds.

I thought I would find this in the book *Linear Orderings* by Rosenstein, but it does not occur; however it should exist somewhere...

Comment: As far as I can see, your relations are both strict orders. As far as I know every strict preorder is always a strict partial order.

Comment: I must be using definitions wrongly then, I'll edit to get large orders.

Answer (score 1):

Let P(x) be the unique A in P = $\Pi$ with x in A. 
Easier to use is the equivalent definition  
x <=' y when exists a in P(x), b in P(y) with a <= b.

Clearly, x <=' x. 
 
If P(x) = P(y), then exists a in P(x) $\cap$ P(y) with a <= a. 
. . Thus x <=' y and y <=' x. 
If x <=' y and y <=' x, then exists 
. . a,b in P(x), c,d in P(y) with a <= c, d <= b. 
If d <= a, then a in P(y) and P(x) = P(y). 
If a <= d, then d in P(x) and P(x) = P(y). 
 
If x <=' y, y <=' z, then exists  
. . a in P(x), b,c in P(y), d in P(z) with a <= b, c <= d. 
If a <= c, then a <= d and x <=' z. 
If c <= a, then a in P(y), so P(x) = P(y), c in P(x), x <=' z.

I prefer the alternative of ordering the partition P by 
A <=* B when exists a in A, b in B with a <= b. 
 
Clearly A <=* A. 
 
If A <=* B, B <=* A, then 
. . exists a,b in A, x,y in B with a <= x, y <= b. 
If y <= a, then a in B, A = B. 
If a <= y, then y in A, A = B.

If A <=* B, B <=* C, then 
. . exists a in A, b,b' in B, c in C with a <= b, b' <= c. 
If a <= b', then a <= c and A <=* C. 
If b' <= a, then a in B, so A = B, A <=* C.

With that order for P, the quasi-order <=' can be recovered:
. . x <=' y iff exists A,B in P with x in A, y in B, A <=* B.

Comment: Thanks for the description and alternative ordering; do you know a reference for this?